# Laravel 8: Retrofitting CDN Vuetify 2 - Custom components

Tags: vuetify.js, laravel-8

I wonder if you may help.

I have a legacy Laravel 8 application which we are using Vuetify 2. Essentially, a page is `Old` or `Vuetify`.

So, I created a layout, `app-vue`. This just includes Vue/Vuetify via CDN.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

This just has a @yield('content'), nothing special.

Then, in the blade file for `Vuetified` pages, I have something like:

```
@extends('layouts.app-vue')

@section('content')
<template>Some stuff here</template>
<script>
    const vueApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify({
            icons: {
                iconfont: 'fa'
            },
            theme: {
                themes: {
                    light: { 
                        background: '#f0f1f3'
                    }
                } 
            }
        }),
.......
<script>
```

Now, whilst this isn't the best solution, it works fine for the pages that have been added.

The problem is, I can't get custom components working.

I've created `resources/js/components/Test.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>TEST</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'test'
    }
</script>
```

And modified app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('test', require('./components/Test.vue').default);

window.Vuetify = require('vuetify');
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

Then in one of the existing blade templates, as a test, just included `<test></test>` to see if it works, but it's complaining that test component hasn't been registered.

I'm assuming I need to alter the `const vueApp = new Vue({ .. });` declaration to pick up the vuetify that was window. Vuetify with the custom component - but JS isn't my strong point, and because I'm not using webpack etc. (and don't really want to) I can't find information I need to make this work.

Disclaimer: Pages are either 100% Vuetify, or not - I don't need to have vuetify components on "old" pages. So if I'm missing something that's better which would allow this, that would be good to know.

This is an internal tool on a local server with just me developing with a single development environment - but I don't really want to have to mess with webpack or change to vue routes etc. as it's not really required for any of this - the old pages aren't likely to change any time soon so still need to work.

The project doesn't use webpack, SCSS or anything it's just Laravel but with a simple JS/CSS setup, which is why the CDN route was chosen and probably will want to stick with this.

Tried a lot of research, but a lot of it is non-applicable, or my gap in JS knowledge isn't helping me understand the solution.